# show div depending on link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make that click on link show specific div. Something like lightbox effect. I managed to make that click on link loads and animate `div` with `class` pop but I need to show specific content in it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .pop{
        background-color: rgba(17,17,17,0.50);
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        display:none;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pro a').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          $('.pop').fadeIn(function(){
            $(this).css({'display':'block'},550);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <div class="pro">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="pop" id="1">
    <div class="mem">profile 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pop" id="2">
    <div class="mem">profile 2</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stakic_igor/y962forf/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pro a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.pop').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(function () {
            $(this).css({
                'display': 'block'
            }, 550);
        });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y962forf/2/)**

Comment: all solutions were good but I choose this answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use html5 `data-` attribute to achieve this.Add it to the anchor tags to keep track which div to show as popup and utilize its id in the click event:

### HTML:

```
<div class="pro"> 
 <a href="#" data-id="first">first</a>
 <a href="#" data-id="second">second</a>
 <a href="#" data-id="third">third</a>

</div>
<div class="pop" id="first">
    <div class="mem">profile 1</div>
</div>
<div class="pop" id="second">
    <div class="mem">profile 1</div>
</div>
<div class="pop" id="third">
    <div class="mem">profile 1</div>
</div>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pro a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.pop').hide(); // hide previous popup div
        var id = $(this).data("id"); // get the div id which to show
        $('#' + id).fadeIn(function () {  // show cuurent click link's popup
            $(this).css({
                'display': 'block'
            }, 550);
        });
    });

});
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/n7j8o66f/

Comment: Or better still, use `data-show="#id-here"` in case you want to reference a class in future (with `.class-here`). Just get rid of `'#' + ` to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you all very much!I am new to jQuery so that was problem to me. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the last div that you showed. Try this:

```
var lastElement = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pro a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.pop').fadeIn(function(){
            if(lastElement)
                 $(lastElement).css({'display':'none'},550);            
            $(this).css({'display':'block'},550);
            lastElement = this;
        });
    });

    });
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jjardim/y962forf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS-only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/35qnxome/.  If you would like to persist the state of your selection, then instead of using `tabindex` property and `:focus` pseudo-class combination, you can use radio `input` and `label` and `:checked` pseudo-class.

HTML:

```
<div class="pro"> 
    <a href="#" data-id="first" tabindex = "1">first</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="second" tabindex = "2">second</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="third" tabindex = "3">third</a>
    <div class="pop" id="first">
        <div class="mem">profile 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pop" id="second">
        <div class="mem">profile 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pop" id="third">
        <div class="mem">profile 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pro > div {
    height: 500px;
    display: none;
}

.pro > div:first-of-type {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.pro > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.pro > div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.pro > a {
    outline: 0;
}

.pro > a:first-of-type:focus ~ div:first-of-type, 
.pro > a:nth-of-type(2):focus ~ div:nth-of-type(2), 
.pro > a:nth-of-type(3):focus ~ div:nth-of-type(3) {
    display: block;
}
```